# Would that version of parameter free replacement be equivalent to replacement?

Tags: set-theory

What's the consistency strength of the following theory?

**Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \implies x=y$

**Separation:** $\forall A \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in A \land \phi)$, whenever $x$ doesn't occur in $\phi$.

**Ranks:** $\forall x \exists   \alpha \,  (  x \hookrightarrow \alpha \land x \in V_\alpha \land \not \exists \beta: \alpha=\beta+1)$

Where $ x\hookrightarrow \alpha$ signify existence of an injection from $x$ to $\alpha$

$V_\alpha$ is defined in the usual manner as the $\alpha^{th}$ stage of the von Neumann hierarchy.

This theory does prove: *Empty, Pairing, Set union, Power, Infinity, Foundation, and Choice.*

I think $\langle V_{\omega_\alpha}, \in ^{V_{\omega_\alpha}}\rangle$, where $\omega_\alpha=\alpha$ would qualify as a model of the theory with the above axioms.

Now, if we add the following form of parameter free replacement, would that be equiconsistent with ZFC?

**Parameter free Replacement:** if $\phi(y)$ is a formula in *ONE* free varaible $y$, then:

$\forall x \in A \, \exists! y \, ( \phi(y) \land x \in y) \land \\ \forall y: \phi(y) \to \exists! x \in A (x \in y) \\ \implies \\\exists B \, \forall y \, (y \in B \leftrightarrow \phi(y))$

My rationale for this equivalence is because of existence of *pointwise* definable models of ZFC, for which the above axiom would (I suppose) be equivalent to full replacement.